# Unable to decrypt AES128 in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, aescryptoserviceprovider

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *key = @"2A8B7BF7-9BC8-4991-8A84-DBA96F10EED2";
    NSString *secret1 = @"1122334455";

    NSString *secret = @"Xf0iDyPDDWBR5wnpT9keoA==";


      NSData * encrypted = [[secret1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:[NSData dataWithBytes:[[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes] length:16]    initializationVector:[NSData dataWithBytes:[[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes] length:16] options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:nil];

    NSLog(@"encrypted %@",encrypted);
    NSString *str = [self base64forData:encrypted];

       NSLog (@"String is %@",str);


  //  NSData *data1 = [self base64DataFromString:secret];




    NSData *data = [encrypted decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm:kCCAlgorithmAES128 key:[NSData dataWithBytes:[[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes] length:16] initializationVector:[[key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] bytes] length:16]  options:kCCOptionPKCS7Padding error:nil];

      NSLog(@"data1 %@ %@",data,[secret1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
       //   NSLog(@"data1 %@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]]);

}


- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] ;
}


- (NSData *)base64DataFromString: (NSString *)string
{
    unsigned long ixtext, lentext;
    unsigned char ch, inbuf[4], outbuf[3];
    short i, ixinbuf;
    Boolean flignore, flendtext = false;
    const unsigned char *tempcstring;
    NSMutableData *theData;

    if (string == nil)
    {
        return [NSData data];
    }

    ixtext = 0;

    tempcstring = (const unsigned char *)[string UTF8String];

    lentext = [string length];

    theData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity: lentext];

    ixinbuf = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ixtext >= lentext)
        {
            break;
        }

        ch = tempcstring [ixtext++];

        flignore = false;

        if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            ch = ch - 'A';
        }
        else if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
        {
            ch = ch - 'a' + 26;
        }
        else if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9'))
        {
            ch = ch - '0' + 52;
        }
        else if (ch == '+')
        {
            ch = 62;
        }
        else if (ch == '=')
        {
            flendtext = true;
        }
        else if (ch == '/')
        {
            ch = 63;
        }
        else
        {
            flignore = true;
        }

        if (!flignore)
        {
            short ctcharsinbuf = 3;
            Boolean flbreak = false;

            if (flendtext)
            {
                if (ixinbuf == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if ((ixinbuf == 1) || (ixinbuf == 2))
                {
                    ctcharsinbuf = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ctcharsinbuf = 2;
                }

                ixinbuf = 3;

                flbreak = true;
            }

            inbuf [ixinbuf++] = ch;

            if (ixinbuf == 4)
            {
                ixinbuf = 0;

                outbuf[0] = (inbuf[0] << 2) | ((inbuf[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
                outbuf[1] = ((inbuf[1] & 0x0F) << 4) | ((inbuf[2] & 0x3C) >> 2);
                outbuf[2] = ((inbuf[2] & 0x03) << 6) | (inbuf[3] & 0x3F);

                for (i = 0; i < ctcharsinbuf; i++)
                {
                    [theData appendBytes: &outbuf[i] length: 1];
                }
            }

            if (flbreak)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return theData;
}

@end
```

And category for encryption

```
#import <Foundation/NSData.h>
#import <Foundation/NSError.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

extern NSString * const kCommonCryptoErrorDomain;

@interface NSError (CommonCryptoErrorDomain)
+ (NSError *) errorWithCCCryptorStatus: (CCCryptorStatus) status;
@end

@interface NSData (CommonDigest)

- (NSData *) MD2Sum;
- (NSData *) MD4Sum;
- (NSData *) MD5Sum;

- (NSData *) SHA1Hash;
- (NSData *) SHA224Hash;
- (NSData *) SHA256Hash;
- (NSData *) SHA384Hash;
- (NSData *) SHA512Hash;

@end

@interface NSData (CommonCryptor)

- (NSData *) AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;
- (NSData *) decryptedAES256DataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;

- (NSData *) DESEncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;
- (NSData *) decryptedDESDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;

- (NSData *) CASTEncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;
- (NSData *) decryptedCASTDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error;

@end

@interface NSData (LowLevelCommonCryptor)

- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;
- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;
- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                    initializationVector: (id) iv       // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;

- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;
- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;
- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                    initializationVector: (id) iv       // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error;


@end

@interface NSData (CommonHMAC)

- (NSData *) HMACWithAlgorithm: (CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm;
- (NSData *) HMACWithAlgorithm: (CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm key: (id) key;

@end
```

.m File

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "NSData+CommonCrypto.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>

NSString * const kCommonCryptoErrorDomain = @"CommonCryptoErrorDomain";

@implementation NSError (CommonCryptoErrorDomain)

+ (NSError *) errorWithCCCryptorStatus: (CCCryptorStatus) status
{
    NSString * description = nil, * reason = nil;

    switch ( status )
    {
        case kCCSuccess:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Success", @"Error description");
            break;

        case kCCParamError:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Parameter Error", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Illegal parameter supplied to encryption/decryption algorithm", @"Error reason");
            break;

        case kCCBufferTooSmall:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Buffer Too Small", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Insufficient buffer provided for specified operation", @"Error reason");
            break;

        case kCCMemoryFailure:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Memory Failure", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Failed to allocate memory", @"Error reason");
            break;

        case kCCAlignmentError:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Alignment Error", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Input size to encryption algorithm was not aligned correctly", @"Error reason");
            break;

        case kCCDecodeError:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Decode Error", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Input data did not decode or decrypt correctly", @"Error reason");
            break;

        case kCCUnimplemented:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Unimplemented Function", @"Error description");
            reason = NSLocalizedString(@"Function not implemented for the current algorithm", @"Error reason");
            break;

        default:
            description = NSLocalizedString(@"Unknown Error", @"Error description");
            break;
    }

    NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [userInfo setObject: description forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

    if ( reason != nil )
        [userInfo setObject: reason forKey: NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];

    NSError * result = [NSError errorWithDomain: kCommonCryptoErrorDomain code: status userInfo: userInfo];
    #if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
        [userInfo release];
    #endif

    return ( result );
}

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation NSData (CommonDigest)

- (NSData *) MD2Sum
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_MD2_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_MD2( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_MD2_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) MD4Sum
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_MD4( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_MD4_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) MD5Sum
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_MD5( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) SHA1Hash
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_SHA1( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) SHA224Hash
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_SHA224( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) SHA256Hash
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_SHA256( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) SHA384Hash
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_SHA384( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

- (NSData *) SHA512Hash
{
    unsigned char hash[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    (void) CC_SHA512( [self bytes], (CC_LONG)[self length], hash );
    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: hash length: CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH] );
}

@end

@implementation NSData (CommonCryptor)

- (NSData *) AES256EncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmAES128
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedAES256DataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmAES128
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

- (NSData *) DESEncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmDES
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedDESDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmDES
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

- (NSData *) CASTEncryptedDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmCAST
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedCASTDataUsingKey: (id) key error: (NSError **) error
{
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;
    NSData * result = [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: kCCAlgorithmCAST
                                                  key: key
                                              options: kCCOptionPKCS7Padding
                                                error: &status];

    if ( result != nil )
        return ( result );

    if ( error != NULL )
        *error = [NSError errorWithCCCryptorStatus: status];

    return ( nil );
}

@end

static void FixKeyLengths( CCAlgorithm algorithm, NSMutableData * keyData, NSMutableData * ivData )
{
    NSUInteger keyLength = [keyData length];
    switch ( algorithm )
    {
        case kCCAlgorithmAES128:
        {
            if ( keyLength < 16 )
            {
                [keyData setLength: 16];
            }
            else if ( keyLength < 24 )
            {
                [keyData setLength: 24];
            }
            else
            {
                [keyData setLength: 32];
            }

            break;
        }

        case kCCAlgorithmDES:
        {
            [keyData setLength: 8];
            break;
        }

        case kCCAlgorithm3DES:
        {
            [keyData setLength: 24];
            break;
        }

        case kCCAlgorithmCAST:
        {
            if ( keyLength < 5 )
            {
                [keyData setLength: 5];
            }
            else if ( keyLength > 16 )
            {
                [keyData setLength: 16];
            }

            break;
        }

        case kCCAlgorithmRC4:
        {
            if ( keyLength > 512 )
                [keyData setLength: 512];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    [ivData setLength: [keyData length]];
}

@implementation NSData (LowLevelCommonCryptor)

- (NSData *) _runCryptor: (CCCryptorRef) cryptor result: (CCCryptorStatus *) status
{
    size_t bufsize = CCCryptorGetOutputLength( cryptor, (size_t)[self length], true );
    void * buf = malloc( bufsize );
    size_t bufused = 0;
  size_t bytesTotal = 0;
    *status = CCCryptorUpdate( cryptor, [self bytes], (size_t)[self length], 
                            buf, bufsize, &bufused );
    if ( *status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        free( buf );
        return ( nil );
    }

  bytesTotal += bufused;

    // From Brent Royal-Gordon (Twitter: architechies):
    //  Need to update buf ptr past used bytes when calling CCCryptorFinal()
    *status = CCCryptorFinal( cryptor, buf + bufused, bufsize - bufused, &bufused );
    if ( *status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        free( buf );
        return ( nil );
    }

  bytesTotal += bufused;

    return ( [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: buf length: bytesTotal] );
}

- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
    return ( [self dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: algorithm
                                         key: key
                        initializationVector: nil
                                     options: 0
                                       error: error] );
}

- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
  return ( [self dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: algorithm
                                         key: key
                        initializationVector: nil
                                     options: options
                                       error: error] );
}

- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key
                    initializationVector: (id) iv
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

    NSParameterAssert([key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
    NSParameterAssert(iv == nil || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

    NSMutableData * keyData, * ivData;
    if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] )
        keyData = (NSMutableData *) [key mutableCopy];
    else
        keyData = [[key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

    if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
        ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
    else
        ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil

    #if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
        [keyData autorelease];
        [ivData autorelease];
    #endif
    // ensure correct lengths for key and iv data, based on algorithms
    FixKeyLengths( algorithm, keyData, ivData );

    status = CCCryptorCreate( kCCEncrypt, algorithm, options,
                           [keyData bytes], [key length], [keyData bytes],
                           &cryptor );

    if ( status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        if ( error != NULL )
            *error = status;
        return ( nil );
    }

    NSData * result = [self _runCryptor: cryptor result: &status];
    if ( (result == nil) && (error != NULL) )
        *error = status;

    CCCryptorRelease( cryptor );

    return ( result );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
    return ( [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: algorithm
                                         key: key
                        initializationVector: nil
                                     options: 0
                                       error: error] );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
  return ( [self decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: algorithm
                                         key: key
                        initializationVector: nil
                                     options: options
                                       error: error] );
}

- (NSData *) decryptedDataUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                     key: (id) key      // data or string
                    initializationVector: (id) iv       // data or string
                                 options: (CCOptions) options
                                   error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
{
    CCCryptorRef cryptor = NULL;
    CCCryptorStatus status = kCCSuccess;

    NSParameterAssert([key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);
    NSParameterAssert(iv == nil || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

    NSMutableData * keyData, * ivData;
    if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] )
        keyData = (NSMutableData *) [key mutableCopy];
    else
        keyData = [[key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];

    if ( [iv isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
        ivData = [[iv dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy];
    else
        ivData = (NSMutableData *) [iv mutableCopy];    // data or nil

    #if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
        [keyData autorelease];
        [ivData autorelease];
    #endif

    // ensure correct lengths for key and iv data, based on algorithms
    FixKeyLengths( algorithm, keyData, ivData );

    status = CCCryptorCreate( kCCDecrypt, algorithm, options,
                           [keyData bytes], [keyData length], [ivData bytes],
                           &cryptor );

    if ( status != kCCSuccess )
    {
        if ( error != NULL )
            *error = status;
        return ( nil );
    }

    NSData * result = [self _runCryptor: cryptor result: &status];
    if ( (result == nil) && (error != NULL) )
        *error = status;

    CCCryptorRelease( cryptor );

    return ( result );
}

@end

@implementation NSData (CommonHMAC)

- (NSData *) HMACWithAlgorithm: (CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm
{
    return ( [self HMACWithAlgorithm: algorithm key: nil] );
}

- (NSData *) HMACWithAlgorithm: (CCHmacAlgorithm) algorithm key: (id) key
{
    NSParameterAssert(key == nil || [key isKindOfClass: [NSData class]] || [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]);

    NSData * keyData = nil;
    if ( [key isKindOfClass: [NSString class]] )
        keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    else
        keyData = (NSData *) key;

    // this could be either CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH or CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH. SHA1 is larger.
    unsigned char buf[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac( algorithm, [keyData bytes], [keyData length], [self bytes], [self length], buf );

    return ( [NSData dataWithBytes: buf length: (algorithm == kCCHmacAlgMD5 ? CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH : CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)] );
}

@end
```

Encryption is working fine but i am not able to decrypt it please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aes 128 encryption uses the Initial vector value you can pass the value using SHA256